# Bash script to spawn and execute commands

Tags: linux, bash, expect

I am trying to create a bash script to ssh into a session and run a command then exit out of the session. currently this is what i have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ssh root@sc
expect "assword:"
send "password\r"
expect "#"
send "cd /data2/someDirectory\r"------> don't see this command being executed
```

and the output

```
[user@San ddb]$ test1
spawn ssh root@sc
root@sc's password:
SC02 RH 7.3 (0000009B 02.11.0.1)
[root@sc /]# [user@san1 ddb]$
[user@san1 ddb]$
```

So my question is why isn't the directory being set to myDirectory and it just exits out of the session?

Comment: Why are you doing this?  Set up your keys so that you don't need to give a password, then execute `ssh user@remote cmd`

Comment: That's not a `bash` script; it's an `expect` script.

Comment: add a `send "pwd\r"` or `send "ls -l\r"` after your cd cmd and see if you get anything. Good luck.

Comment: In a recent update of openssh they changed the default such that `root` won't be able to login with password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `expect` script is doing what you are intending but is quitting once the job is `send` is done.

set some "expectation" like `expect "$"` at the end of the script and try.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ssh root@10.200.2.19
expect "assword:"
send "pass\r"
expect "#"
send  "\r"
send  "pwd\r"
send  "\r"
send  "cd /tmp\r"
send  "touch dummy\r"
expect "$"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need expect for this:

```
ssh root@host 'cd /tmp; touch afile'
```

For password-less operation, set up ssh keys. Here's a decent tutorial: http://support.suso.com/supki/SSH_Tutorial_for_Linux